# Running DOS command from vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I want to run the following command from vb.net code.  When I put it in process.start("  ")
it returns syntax error.  Please advise

```
>E:\UnInstall\SQLServer\SQLServerExpress2008\SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe / SQ/SAPWD="testpwd123"/security=SQL/BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Enabled"/TCPENABLED="1"/NPENABLED="0"/INDICATEPROGRESS="True"/INSTANCENAME="CBEInstance"/IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS="True"
```

Comment: Please post your code, specifically the process.start(... line.  I am thinking you need to escape the double quotes at least i.e. " -> ""

Comment: No version of DOS has ever been capable of running VB.Net.

Comment: @valverij This is VB, not C#

Answer (score 0):

You specify the file to run with `Process.StartInfo.Filename`, and the command line arguments with `Process.StartInfo.Arguments`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dim DosRun As Process = New Process
    DosRun.StartInfo.FileName = "E:\UnInstall\SQLServer\SQLServerExpress2008\SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe"
    DosRun.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("SQ/SAPWD=testpwd123/security=SQL/BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE=Enabled/TCPENABLED=1/NPENABLED=0/INDICATEPROGRESS=True/INSTANCENAME=CBEInstance/IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS=True")
    DosRun.Start()
```